# trying to make an already clickable div open fancybox

Tags: javascript, wordpress, fancybox

im not much of a coder. just sort of self taught through wordpress. i have a site I've hacked together from a blank theme and I've taken it pretty far.

the last step i want to do is have my `#brick` open the permalink page with either `rel`, or `class` of fancybox.

using WP fancybox plugin.

here is what I'm doing to make the div clickable in the first place

```
<div id="brick" onclick="location.href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>';" style="cursor:pointer;">
```

where in this line would i add `rel="fancybox"` or `class="fancybox"`?

thank you in advance.

Comment: oops sorry here is the site! http://throughthelattice.com/

Comment: Adding the *class* fancybox to your `<div>` wouldn't be enough; you would need to remove the attribute `onclick`, otherwise the permalink will always open in the browser's window and not in fancybox, even if you have set the *class* fancybox. Additionally, you have other issues : you cannot use the same `ID` in two or more elements in the same page, `IDs`have to be **unique** ... and, you are also loading two instances of jQuery when you only need one (the latest version ideally) ... and you cannot use `$()` (in WP) because you will trigger js errors, use `jQuery()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have the `href` set in your `<a>` tag, like this part of your code.

```
<h2 class="entry-title"><a rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to Art and commerce in the digital age" href="http://throughthelattice.com/art-and-commerce-in-the-digital-age/">Art and commerce in the digital age</a></h2>
```

... then, I would do :

1. Remove this line

   ```
   <script src="//throughthelattice.com/wp-content/themes/lh_wordpress_blank_theme/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
   ```

   ... you already loaded jQuery v1.8.3 in your `<head>` section
2. Replace all `id="brick"` by `class="brick"`
3. Replace this script

   ```
   <script>
   $('#brick').fancybox();
   </script>
   ```

   ... by this :

   ```
   <script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function () {
       jQuery("a[rel='bookmark']").fancybox({
           "type": "iframe"
       });
   }); // ready
   </script>
   ```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m3Fce/)**

Comment: THANK YOU JFK and others for your help. I was able to do it with JFKs suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Rather straight forward to add `rel` or `class` properties to an element:

```
<div id="brick" onclick="location.href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>';" style="cursor:pointer;" rel="fancybox" class="fancybox">
```

And the JavaScript could be:

```
$("div.fancybox").fancybox();
```

or whatever selector you'd like to use. Since you can select with jQuery using a combination of `class`, `id` or `tag name`.

Comment: thanks sweets, not working. i wonder if there is a conflict somewhere with #brick since its being used as the masonry item

Comment: would i have to edit the code: $("div.fancybox").fancybox(); to something like $("a #brick").fancybox();?

Comment: @user1071890 I think your problem is that your have `id="brick"` on multiple elements. FYI `id` names must be unique in the whole page.

Comment: i see. so making it a class instead might work? damn how can somehting have multiple classes. unless rel="fancybox" is enough to trigger

Comment: well thank you for your time sweetamylase. ill keep tinkering